# Need to change section to Roman, but keep Arabic for for subsection and subsubsection

Tags: latex, roman-numerals

I need to change my section numbering from Arabic, to Roman, beet keep the Arabic numbering in subsections and subsubsections. For example:

I. Section

1.1. Subsection

1.1.1. Subsubsection

II. Section

2.1 Subsection

...

So I know that with sections i can do "\renewcommand \thesection{\roman{section}}", but this command changes also subsections and subsubsections, like that:

I. Section

I.1. Subsection

I.1.1. Subsubsection

II Section

II.1. Subsection

...

So I need to keep subsections ans subsubsections from Roman numbering.

Comment: I guess you'll find http://tex.stackexchange.com/ a better place to ask future questions of this kind: more and potentially better-informed responses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These two lines did it for me:

```
\renewcommand \thesection{\roman{section}}
\renewcommand \thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Subsubsection also works, I assume because it takes its section number from subsection.

Comment: Or in a "book" environment, `\renewcommand \thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{part}}`

Comment: Use \renewcommand \thesection{\Roman{section}} so as to have sections numbered as I, II, III...